# How to access variable from one keyword to another key

Tags: automation, robotframework

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case
    When I post A POST Request
    Then verify the status code

*** Keywords ***
I Post A POST Request
    &{resp}=  create dictionary    status_code=200
    set suite variable  ${resp.status_code}

Verify The status Code
    ${actual_response_code} =  Get Variable Value  ${resp.status_code}
    should be equal as strings  200  ${actual_response_code}
```

${resp.status_code} I need this variable to access in Verify The status Code. I got error Variable definition not found

Answer (score 1):

`${resp.status_code}` is the key "status_code" inside the dictionary "resp", that's why it didn't work.

A much easier approach will be if the 1st keyword returned a value, and you pass it to the second. Thus you wouldn't depend on their execution order, and wouldn't depend on a global state that should be guaranteed. Something like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case
    ${response}=    When I post A POST Request
    Then verify the status code    ${response} 

*** Keywords ***
I Post A POST Request
    &{resp}=  create dictionary    status_code=200
    [Return]   ${resp}

Verify The status Code
    [Arguments]    ${response_object} 
    ${actual_response_code} =  Get Variable Value  ${response_object.status_code}
    should be equal as strings  200  ${actual_response_code}
```